# How can I change program icons?

Tags: windows, icons, resources

I have some old Python programs that I compiled with a tool called py2exe. Now I no longer have the sources but I would like to change the program icons to something meaningful. I'd also like to change the icons on some other programs to better suit my desktop. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: "change the icons on some other programs to better suit my desktop" : in this case, it's not about changing icon of a program, but of a shortcut to this program, I'm guessing ?

Comment: No, most of the icons on my desktop are portable executable, like putty or winscp.

Comment: It'd be safer, then, to replace them with shortcuts. One or two programs don't like having their stuff changed, and of course, anything that relies on an md5 will return wrong.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/):

[image]

Although this is fine for your programs, it is likely against the EULA for the commercial applications you have so you may want to read over them.

Comment: can't do without it :) +1

Answer (score 2):

There is also [**XN Resource Editor**](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm).

[image: XN Resource Editor]

Comment: +1 ^^ Better than ResHacker, and since it had x64 support as soon as it was needed, and far before ResHacker, I switched long ago.